# Moment.js WeekNumbers in an Array

Tags: momentjs

I would like to put week numbers into an Array. Can anybody help me?

I tried this:

```js
var week = [];
var now = moment().week();

while(now) {
  var current = moment().week();
  week.push(moment().week());
  now--;
}

console.log("Week:" + week);
```

The output is always:

```
Week:43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43
```

But I would like `1,2,3,4,5, ... 50,51,52,53`

Comment: Have to written any code for that?

Comment: Edit your question. Dont post as answer

Comment: Check answer is posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var current = moment().weeksInYear();
var week = []; 

for(var i=1;i<=current;i++)
{
    week.push(i);
}

console.log(week);
```

Try this one. You have to use `moment().weeksInYear();` out of loop

Comment: Ok it´s better. The Result is Week:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43 but what is with the other weeks ?

Comment: use moment().weeksInYear(); for getting total week in year

Comment: Glad that is help you. That is really great if you give upvote. Thanks.!

Comment: Hello 
When i chose a Week also Week 44 how can i get the Date also 30.10 - 5.11
thx